# CodeIgniter form validation not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a form set up in a controller that both loads the form and its previously populated contents from a database and processes the form as needed. The problem is $this->form_validation->run() never evaluates to FALSE, even if rules are not met.

Controller:

```
public function edit_version($node, $lang)
{
    // load form validation class
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    // set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("title|Title|required");

    // run validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)
    {
        // save input to database
        die("validation successful");
    }
    else
    {
        // either validation was not passed or no data to validate
        // load page edition view and display databse contents

        // load page model
        $this->load->model("page_model");

        // get the page from database
        $data["page"] = $this->page_model->get_page($node, $lang);

        // load views
        $this->load->view("admin/header.php", array("title" => "Edit page no.: $node, $lang version - Admin"));
        $this->load->view("admin/pages/edit_page.php", $data);
        $this->load->view("admin/footer.php");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Page_model extends CI_Model
{
public function get_page($node, $lang)
{
    // load the page
    return $this->db->get_where("pages", array("node" => $node, "lang" => $lang))->row();
}

public function save_version($page)
{
    $this->db->where("node", $page["node"]);
    $this->db->where("lang", $page["lang"]);
    $this->db->update("pages", $page);
}

public function search($query)
{
    return $this->db->get_where("pages", $query)->result();
}
}
```

View:

```
<h2>Edit page</h2>
<?php
// load form helper
    $this->load->helper("form");

// open a form
echo form_open("admin/page/{$page->node}/edit/{$page->lang}");

// print validation errors
echo validation_errors();

// title and content fields
echo form_label("Title: ", "title");
echo form_input("title", set_value("title", $page->title));

// aesthetic line break
echo "<br>";

echo form_label("Content: ", "content") . "<br>";
echo form_textarea("content", set_value("content", $page->content));

// save button and close form
echo form_submit("submit", "Save page");
echo form_close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**syntax for setting rule is**

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Label', 'rule1|rule2|rule3');
```

by considering rules your set rule line will be

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title', 'required");
```

Comment: yes dude you are right... i had the same problem, even spelling mistakes of form fields fail the validation.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a CodeIgniter seasoned dev but from documentation is the proper syntax not the following?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("title","Title","required");
```

As per this link:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("title","Title","required");
```

instead of this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','required');
```

I have tested this. It works like a Charm.